# Having issues with handling text field

Tags: apex, map, string, formatting

I have one requirement where text field have information like below format:

```
String name = 'email,phone(Jason),mobile,address(Mason)';
```

Now what I want to do is create a `Map<Key, List<String>>` where key will be name in brackets ex: Jason/Mason and values will be whatever is before that name in parentheses. So output should be like:

```
OUTPUT: {Jason=(email,Phone), Mason=(mobile,address)}
```

I had tried different ways but unable to format string 'email,phone(Jason), mobile,address(Mason)'. As there are parentheses Is it even possible to achieve this?

Comment: Is the format of the text field set in stone here? The easiest solution here would probably be to use JSON for the input text. Otherwise, I imagine you're going to be using some combination of regex and methods from the `String` class. You should also edit your question to show us the attempt(s) you've made so far and include sample output from them (and/or the full, unmodified text and stack trace of any error(s) you're getting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an oddly weird request, but assuming you haven't overgeneralized, you could write something like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> results = new Map<String, List<String>>();
String name = 'email,phone(Jason),mobile,address(Mason)';
while(name != '') {
    String key = name.substringBetween('(',')');
    String[] values = name.substringBefore('(').split(',');
    results.put(key, values);
    name = name.substringAfter(')').removeStart(',');
}
```

Which outputs:

```
{Jason=(email, phone), Mason=(mobile, address)}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. This one is so simple and clean. I was making it over complicated by tracking it using indexing.